# Appium: Unable to identify accessibility ID on iOS app - IONIC 4

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, appium, ionic4

I am trying to fetch Ionic elements using Appium and Gigafox but no matter what approach I use, I am unable to fetch them. Appium and GigaFox both are unable to detect the `id` and `name` parameters which I am providing in the HTML file. Although, I am able to get the `id` on Android (which is mapped to `resource-id`) with the same approach. I did go through multiple threads on Appium's official forums and other similar questions on SO but non has a resolution.

Here is the code implementation.

`<ion-segment-button id="internalButton" name="internal_button" aria-label="internalButton">This is a test</ion-segment-button>`

I am new to ionic development and any direction on this would be highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find something around this?

Comment: use this `(ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)" or set (click)="segmentChanged($event)" `

Comment: @RaviAshara the issue is when we try to access the element via Appium.

Comment: kindly set and example code of the function internalButtonAction()

Comment: I have updated the question so that there is no confusion. The function has nothing to do with what we are asking about, so removed it all together.